# Splitting large chunk of text into individual words

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using JS/JQuery I parse some data from my server and then do the following to display it onto my webpage

```
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = info_data;
```

The result of this is naturally one chunk of data that is displayed on the page. I would like to be able to further parse this data so that each word can be individually formatted/hyperlinked and then display in a list for example.

Because the size of data can be dynamic I am not sure of a way in which this could be done and would be grateful for any assistance.

The HTML and CSS for this are extremely simple as of now and are as follows:

```
<div class="info_list" id="info"></div>

.info_list
{
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    color: #069;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Example currently:

```
Blah Blah2 Blah3 Blah4 Blah5 etc....
```

Ideal Solution:

```
<hyperlink>Blah
<hyperlink>Blah2
etc........
```

Comment: what are the rules for parsing the string... like what should be the href etc

Comment: It would be a link to itself, each item will be an address

Comment: A word boundary `string.split(/\b/g)`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Gb46j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = info_data.replace(/([^\s]+)/g, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8YwUK/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `var words = info_data.split(" ");` to split your string at every space which will return you an array with all the words of your string ;)

Then you get word 1 by `words[0]` word 2 by `words[1]` and so on.

Then you can add the links by jQuery append:

```
for(var i = 0; i< words.length; i++){
        var newLink = "<a href='"+words[i]+"'>"+words[i]+"</a>";
        $("#info").append(newLink);
    }
```

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLuhX/3/)

Comment: If the number of items is dynamic would I not need more than one ID then HTML wise? How would this work when it comes to displaying it in HTML?

Comment: What does the hyperlink link to? always the same page!? Or where do the hyperlinks come from?

Comment: It would be a link to itself, each item will be an address